# How to set up a http website and a https website on single-ip server in Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server, https, virtual-host, httpd

I want to set up a http website:http://example1.com, and a https website:https://example2.com using the following configuration:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2.com/public_html
    SSLCertificateFile...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile...
    SSLEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

However, if I visit https://example1.com, I am redirected to https://example2.com. If I visit http://example2.com, I am redirected to http://example1.com. This is not what I want. I would like https://example1.com and http://example2.com do not exist at all. How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *will* have to define two more VirtualHost blocks. If Apache cannot find a matching VirtualHost for that name, it will use the first VirtualHost belonging to the port.

Of course, you don't have to serve the same website:

- You can serve an error page, such as a generic *404 Not Found*. This will annoy people.
- For `example2.com`, you can use a RewriteRule to redirect all HTTP visitors to HTTPS.
- For `example1.com`... well, I really don't understand why you wouldn't serve that via HTTPS?

However, you cannot make the browser report that the domain doesn't exist, because it's still the same domain, regardless of how it's accessed.

Comment: I've considered using two more VirtualHost blocks and serving the http/https version of the website I do not want with 404 Not Found. But I think it would do no good to SEO. Using RewriteRule is a feasible method but a little complex. What I want is: when visiting https://example1.com or http://example2.com, it is just like apache is not started, or the website is never set up on the server.

Comment: You csn use Redirect rules which are simpler then RewiteRules, or even get your application to handle this in many cases.

Comment: @peter: "apache is not started" is impossible. You're accessing the same IP address, the same port – you will get the same results. The hostname is only known _after_ Apache accepts and receives the request!

Comment: @peter: As for "good SEO", redirects are fine, but refusing to use HTTPS really doesn't do your website any favours.

Comment: @grawity , Imagine you only set up one https website on your server(one virtual host,listen only on port 443), Search Engines never realize the existence of http version of the website. I think this is the best way for the sake of SEO. Although redirect does no harm to SEO in theory, I feel it is not very natural.